# Open close ServiceHost multiple times

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to figure out how to open and close a ServiceHost object multiple times in a self-hosted WCF app:

what I did:
1. create ServiceHost object

1. call Open()
2. call Closed()
   so far so good.
3. call Open() again, exception: Cannot access a disposed object, which is because CommunicationObject is disposed , makes perfect sense.

How can I open the ServiceHost again in this case without recreating that object again (rather, I'd recreate CommunicationObject if it is possible).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to close the service host and then open it again ? Why the aversion to creating another instance of the service host ?

Comment: because during app life time, I want to control servicehose based on the mode it is in. Of course the app has other things to do, wcf service is only part of it. To me, it seems only the CommunicationObject faulted there is no reason to recreate whole servicehost just because of this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) inherits from CommunicationObject. ServiceHost is the CommunicationObject throwing the exception. Once a CommunicationObject is Closed it cannot be reopened. You'll have to create a new ServiceHost.

The [CommunicationState state machine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/08/14/697065.aspx):

> Every object starts in the Created state and proceeds in a **one-way**
>   progression through the Opening, Opened, Closing, and Closed states.

Comment: ServiceHost inherits from ServiceHostBase, to me, it seems CommunicationObject is composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: And ServceHostBase parent is System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject
so its not a member

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you end goal is but take a look at this article. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/generic_wcf_host.aspx
If that's not the problem you're trying to skin then maybe some of the technicals and application domains is what you are looking for?